# WSO2 Identity Server - Sign in with OpenID like Gmail

Tags: openid, wso2

I have the login via OpenID demo working.  It requires me to pass the openid to the WSO2 server, for example:

```
https://myservername:9443/openid/firstname.lastname
```

What I really want is for the login workflow to look like Gmail.  I.e. if a session isn't started, the user gets redirected to a landing page where they type in their user/name password, provide a pki certificate, etc.  Any suggestions on how to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You need to create OpenID Authentication requests taking `https://myservername:9443/openid/` (note : without name in the url) as the OpenID Identifier.

Simply create an authentication request for the above identifier , redirect the user to IS, then IS will prompt for username and password.